# How to get the right IP Address

Tags: bash, networking, console, ip

I need to write a shell script for the purpose of unblocking the current ip from a server.
The script must run on mac os.

The script is finished i just need to get the right ip adress, the one i connect to the internet with.
If a hit 'ipconfig getifaddr en0' in the console i get the following adress: 127.168.X.XXX. But when I use a service like 'whatismyip.com' im getting 87.188.XXX.XXX. This is the one I need to get in the console.

Any ideas on which command i could use to get the right ip?

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to find out your external ip address. If you have `curl` installed on your system, the quickest way is to use:

```
curl ifconfig.co
```

That will return the ip you are looking for.

Comment: thats great! next question would be if theres a way to resolve the found ipv6 to an ipv4 adress? is there a quick workaround?

Comment: Have a look at the https://ifconfig.co/ page. You can force curl to use ipv4 with `curl -4 ifconfig.co`